# How to restore access to a disabled iCloud data?

Tags: icloud, iphone, password

I've tried my iCloud password too many times and it got disabled. I got the following notification:

> Email has been sent.
>
> When you receive your sign in information, follow the directions in the email to reset your password.
>
> `Return to My Apple ID`

How to restore access to my iCloud data?

Comment: Did you follow the directions in the email?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to https://appleid.apple.com and log in - pay attention to see if you get a message like "This Apple ID has been disabled for security reasons". If not, you can ignore all the emails and just make sure you know your security questions (perhaps choosing new ones if someone is trying to guess your account). If so, your account is locked. There are steps to fix it are here:

- http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204161

If you truly can't make sense of the instructions, you can contact Apple ID support and a human can help explain your situation if needed:

- http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/contact/